# Creating Nested dictionary with multiple hierarchy separated with '.'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to create a multiple hierarchy of nested dictionary. The hierarchy levels are separated with a dot(.) in variable `B` however the final key (`A`) and value (`D`) are fixed.

#### Variables

```
A = "key"
B = "one.two.three.four"
D = "value"
```

#### Desired Output

```
{ one : { two : {three : {four : {key: value}}}}}
```

Here, the length of hierarchy (variable `B`) might increase or decrease based on input. I'm unable to create such dynamic code.

#### My pseudocode Code

```
A = "key"
B = "one.two.three.four"
D = "value"

inner_dictionary = {}
whole_dictionary = {}

lst = B.split('.')
length = len(lst)

for i in range(length):
    new = lst[-1]
    tmp = {A:D}
    inner_dictionary.update(tmp)
    val = { new : inner_dictionary}
    whole_dictionary.update(val)
    lst.pop()

print(whole_dictionary)
```

#### My Output

```
{'four': {'key': 'value'}, 'three': {'key': 'value'}, 'two': {'key': 'value'}, 'one': {'key': 'value'}}
```

I need help on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there any special use case for such desire?

Comment: so there will always be single key and value in final dict ignoring nested levels? am i ryt?

Comment: @Ameya Yes, need to create json dump from file which has multiple hierarchy mentioned in variable B. The pseudo code is just a single iteration but vital piece for the script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```py
A = "key"
B = "one.two.three.four"
D = "value"

x = {A: D}

for k in B.split('.')[::-1]:
    x = {k: x}

print(x)
```

Output:

```py
{'one': {'two': {'three': {'four': {'key': 'value'}}}}}
```

---

Or, in Python 3.8+, using [the walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions):

```py
A = "key"
B = "one.two.three.four"
D = "value"

x = {A: D}
[(x := {k: x}) for k in B.split('.')[::-1]]
print(x)
```

Output:

```py
{'one': {'two': {'three': {'four': {'key': 'value'}}}}}
```

---

Note: the second solution takes a lot more time (you can run the following code to check that):

```py
from timeit import timeit

print(timeit("""A = "key"
B = "one.two.three.four"
D = "value"
x = {A: D}
for k in B.split('.')[::-1]:
    x = {k: x}"""))

print(timeit("""A = "key"
B = "one.two.three.four"
D = "value"
x = {A: D}
[(x := {k: x}) for k in B.split('.')[::-1]]"""))
```

The first one takes about 0.5s, the second one about 1s.

Comment: I would advise against using the walrus operator here, it creates a list that is not used

Comment: Thanks, I added the timings at the end to show comparison

Answer (score 0):

One approach using a single for-loop:

```
A = "key"
B = "one.two.three.four"
D = "value"


start = { A: D }
for k in reversed(B.split(".")):
    start = { k : start }
print(start)
```

**Output**

```
{'one': {'two': {'three': {'four': {'key': 'value'}}}}}
```

This type of problem where a list of values aggregates to a single one can be solved using [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) (a la functional programming):

```
from functools import reduce

A = "key"
B = "one.two.three.four"
D = "value"

res = reduce(lambda x, y: {y: x},  reversed(B.split(".")), {A: D})
```